# Regex выделение классов | методов яп Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть класс яп `Java`. Хочу с помощью `regex` грепать классы | методы из файлов `.java`.

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    protected int lol;

    public Dog(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = -1;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public int humanAge() {
        return this.age > 0 ? this.age * 7 : -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s | Age: %d", this.name, this.age);
    }

}
```

Начал писать что-то подобное, но пока не понимаю как грепнуть весь класс вместе с телом.
`(public )?class [A-Za-z0-9]+ {([.*?s]+)`

Пытался с флагом `re.MULTILINE`, но тщетно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885315/regex-pattern-to-find-java-class-in-java-file

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, Частичное решение. Но все равно большое спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912934/how-to-match-a-method-block-using-regex

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @VictorVosMottor . С его помощью представляю финальный ответ:

`(((|public|final|abstract|private|static|protected)(\s+))?(class)(\s+)(\w+)(<.*>)?(\s+extends\s+\w+)?(<.*>)?(\s+implements\s+)?(.*)?(<.*>)?(\s*))\{$(\s.*)+\}`

Или конкретнее:
https://regex101.com/r/YPcJRh/1/